# What are the minimum system requirements for 12.04 LTS?

Tags: system-requirements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the system requirements for each flavour of Ubuntu Desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavor-of-ubuntu-desktop)

I have a 2nd generation core i3 processor (2.30 GHz). It was preloaded with 64-bit Windows 7. It ran smoothly with 2 GB RAM. Will Ubuntu 64-bit be the same or does it require 4 GB or more?

Comment: Check this for general guideleines on how to upgrade and release notes :http://askubuntu.com/q/110477/56338

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on an HP with Intel Pentium 4 2.8GHZ and 2 Gigs of Ram and it runs great!

Comment: My experience: 10.04 32bit running great on a 256MB P4 1.5GHz. On the other hand, a somewhat old Toshiba notebook failed to load many drivers with 12.04. So I switched to 10.04 and all is great again.