# Will Ubuntu 12.04 run smoothly with these specs?

Tags: installation, hardware, system-requirements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the minimum system requirements for 12.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125280/what-are-the-minimum-system-requirements-for-12-04-lts)

I have a computer with the following specs:

```
Intel Pentium 4 3.00 GHz
2 GB RAM
a PCI Nvidia video card
```

Will Ubuntu run smoothly on this machine?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will. You can check specifications [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements#Recommended_Minimum_System_Requirements).

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu should run smoothly on this machine, but you might have to use Unity 2D rather than regular (3D) Unity for the graphical user interface. This might be selected for you, but if the interface malfunctions or is slow, then click the Ubuntu logo on the login screen and select `Ubuntu 2D` (instead of `Ubuntu`). Please note that this is a per-user setting.

This is assuming your NVidia card is PCI, rather than PCI Express. Any NVidia card for PCI Express should be sufficient to the task of running 3D Unity, though it's possibly you'll need to install the proprietary drivers (using the Additional Drivers utility) to get that to work.

If you want more detailed information, you'll need to tell us the specific model of PCI NVidia graphics card you have. It would also be useful if you told us the exact make and model of your computer or, if that is inapplicable, the make and model of your motherboard.

As [Luka](https://askubuntu.com/users/65678/luka) has [pointed out](https://askubuntu.com/a/141389/22949), you can always check the [system requirements for Ubuntu and its official derivatives](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements#Recommended_Minimum_System_Requirements).