# Will 12.04 LTS install on my old computer?

Tags: system-installation

My old computer has a Soyo SYK7V Dragon Plus mobo.  1 GB PC2100 RAM, FX5500 DDR AGP video card and 80GB HDD.  Will the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS install on this computer?  Reason for asking is because I keep getting an "unrecoverable error" each time I try.
I forget to mention that the CPU is an AMD Athlon XP1900 socket A.

Comment: Similar answered question at http://askubuntu.com/questions/125280/what-are-the-minimum-system-requirements-for-12-04-lts

Comment: I tried using both a CD and DVD medium.  Integrity check of disc is OK.

Comment: @gilloz at what point of installation do you get the error?

Answer (score 2):

Download the alternative ISO and try if that works. It's a text-based installer which runs fine on older PC's.

Link to ISO: [Alternative downloads](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads)

Answer (score 0):

According to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements , you should be able to run Ubuntu.

Can you boot the LiveCD? Is your hard disk intact?

Comment: Yes, to both questions.  I played with the program to check it out in live session, but when it came time to install, I get that error.

Comment: My hard drive had Windows XP and was working fine.  I erased Windows XP when I tried to install Ubuntu 12.04.  I even ran DBAN to wipe the hard drive clean and tried again.

Answer (score 0):

Most people with this error said Alternative installation worked.

1.Boot from your live CD or USB

2.Then at terminal type `sudo apt-get remove ubiquity-slideshow-ubuntu` and continue with installation

3.Continue Installation by right-clicking on desktop to get menu and select Application and select install Xubuntu.

Comment: Yes, I already tried entering that statement in the terminal and it did not work.  I saw that on other threads.

Comment: Try to install 11.10 upgrade from there to 12.04 and see what happens.

Comment: Why would I want to install Xubuntu as oppose to just Ubuntu?

Comment: I installed 10.04 and it seemed to work, but when I installed the updates, I got a failure with regards to my graphics nVidia running on low mode and the screen was locked on that window.

Comment: The main difference is the environment. While Xubuntu restorts to XFCE and Ubuntu make use of Gnome. System perform faster in Xubuntu due to it light yet flexible resources. Not so much difference when a situation like yours is pertinent.

Comment: My problem is when I get that unrecoverable error, it allows me to use my live desktop to troubleshoot the problem, but I have no clue where to start looking for this problem.

Comment: My last advice would be to do XTreset, by putting off your computer, remove the power source by removing the cable from the main power source. Press and hold down the power button for at least 10 minutes. Then, connect the power cable and start your system. Try to repeat the instruction I suggested before(the one you said you've tried).

Comment: Finally did it.  I downloaded and installed the Alternate CD and that did the trick.  Thank you all4naija for the suggestion.  Now for the configuration of everything.  Works great, so far.

Comment: I am glad you did it. You are welcome.