# Installing UBUNTU on a PC with win 8 and win 7 and just remove win 8

Tags: installation, migration

i have a PC with win 7 and win 8 consumer preview, i downloaded UBUNTU 12 and want to replace win 8 by Ubuntu without removing win 7 and erasing my hard disk and i also don't have any option to backup....pls help....

Comment: If you have no 'option to backup' then you can't continue. You must backup anything important in Windows 7 before you go any further. Copy anything important to a backup drive, then search here for 'dual-boot' and see what to expect before you start.

Comment: This question has upvoted answers that directly address what was asked. Furthermore, the OP's situation is not really all that unusual. I recommend against closing this as *too localized*.

Answer (score 2):

First: Backup your data from Windows 8 partition if needed.

Don't worry. Windows 7 will be intact if you take care while installing Ubuntu.

To remove Windows 8 refer to [this](http://techtt.in/how-to-remove-windows-8-from-dual-boot-windows-7/) and [this](http://blog.laptopmag.com/how-to-uninstall-windows-8-from-a-dual-booting-pc).

If not not deleted the Windows 8 partition then from your Windows 7 OS, delete the Windows 8 partition through Disk Management, which can be brought up by right-clicking the My Computer icon. Reboot to see and confirm the changes.

Now with a live CD or live USB flash drive of Ubuntu 12.04, you are ready to go.

1. Boot from the live CD or live USB drive. Use the *Try before Install* option, or if you want to install directly then choose *Install* option.
2. Proceed with installation steps. Select the first default option  *Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7* for ease of installation. (sorry for the wrong optioned screenshot).

[image]

Then at the Partition table, select the *Free space* or *Unallocated space*.

--Select the *Add* option and then allocate the desired  Space for root `/` and swap partitions in ext4 format [search or refer to Ubuntu Guide for the minimum and your RAM based swap space [requirement](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125280/what-are-the-minimum-system-requirements-for-12-04-lts), or you can also select the *Something else* option for manual partitioning. If you want different partitions for `/home`, `/boot`, etc. you can allocate them in the same way.

-- Then select the appropriate drive at the Grub Bootloader Installation option, if there's only a single hard drive then most probably it will be `sda` . And it's done.

You can refer further to the [Official Windows Dual Boot wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot).

Answer (score 0):

Its possible.

- First thing you need to do is to backup all your important data if you have any from Windows 8. Then go to your Windows 7  disk management utility and format the partition containing Windows 8. I assume here that you have installed win7 and win8 in different partitions.
- Now, once you are done with formatting that partition with NTFS. Install a software called as daemon-tools or PowerISO, they emaluate ISO such that you will be able to run your Ubuntu 12.04 iso file without burning a CD.
- Then all you need to do is to use WUBI, its a installer of Ubuntu inside windows(means it won't modify or format your hard drive and there is no risk of data loss).Using that you can install Ubuntu 12.04 easily.

Also Here is a link of how you can use WUBI. [Using Wubi](http://gotchacode.wordpress.com/2010/08/17/install-linux-a-easy-way-without-getting-into-trouble/)

If you are a beginner i will suggest you go this way, it will give you least troubles.

Comment: I disagree to  suggest **wubi** method . If you want to get the Power of Ubuntu 12.04 Ecosystem entirely, do a fresh installation on new partition.

Comment: Actually in this case where we will have a free partition after having removed Windows 8 there is not really a benefit from WUBI. I'd go for [dual-boot](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows). From Windows there is no need to **format** this partition. Just delete the partition and leave it **unpartitioned** - the Ubuntu installation will use and format this later.

Comment: But if someone is a new user, WUBI is the way to go. What if he doesn't feel comfortable using Ubuntu and want to remove ubuntu. Wouldn't he loose access to his Win partition when he formats the Ubuntu 12.04?
So once he feels comfortable with Ubuntu, he can always do a full install. Like he said he don't want to loose any  data, I suggest him a safer way.

Comment: @Takkat I know dual-boot is better, but if someone is a newbie WUBI is better, He can always install Ubuntu in that free space, Wubi lets you select drives, isn't it?

Comment: In that case i will suggest , to try Ubuntu from live media or **Ubuntu in Virtual box** . Wubi has some issues , after trying out in wubi , OP may abandon the use of Ubuntu.

Comment: I never had that kind of experience with Wubi.Wonder why you saying this?

Comment: You can refer [this](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=[wubi]+error.)  , [this](http://ubuntu-with-wubi.blogspot.in/) , [Bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi) or the [Wubi tagged questions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/wubi). I think Wubi is for `Ubuntu alongside Windows Installed System feature trail Rides`. If we go on suggesting to install using Wubi, then Independent Ubuntu/Linux installation will be of no use at all. Since it encourages to depend on Use of .exe Windows executable file.