# Memory requirements for Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the minimum system requirements for 12.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125280/what-are-the-minimum-system-requirements-for-12-04-lts)

I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 on a computer with 1GB of memory,will that suffice?

Answer (score 2):

I have an older Pentium IV myself, with 1GB RAM, from my experience, it's not so much about memory but about the processor. Linux is very respectful about RAM memory usage and besides you can always create a swap partition, so in the end it comes down to the processing power of your PC. If you have at least a dual-core, Ubuntu will work just fine, as long as you don't open too much applications or webpages filled with flash advertisements and banners at same time and as other people said, change to Unity 2D. If you want to be really sure to have a system running smoothly, I strongly recommend Lubuntu, based on Ubuntu 12.04 with lightweight LXDE interface, however it is not LTS (Long term Support), meaning that it will not be supported when 12.10 version arrives. Try Ubuntu first in a Live-USB environment and then check if your system runs fine with it.

Comment: +1 for the speed being more about the processor.  I do have a fast processor so the system responds quickly and 8 GB of RAM, but most of my RAM goes unused most of the time, it hovers around 680MB used. With a large swap partition it will run fine with 1gb but while using the swap is will be slower, but most of the time you will be using only minimal swap.  In fact the minimal req. for a 64 bit install is [512MB](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop#System_requirements)

Comment: Indeed, I agree completely, while running Ubuntu, I get about the same memory usage on laptop and desktop. What makes the difference is the processor power, which allows me to load elements quicker and have a much responsive system on laptop than on desktop, which is a Pentium. If one is going to renew his hardware, bet on processor first, only then on RAM memory, but sometimes people do the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but will be a little slow.

There are many solutions to speed up the system, though:

1. Make sure to create a big (like 4GB) `swap` partition (during the installation process).
2. Switch to Ubuntu 2D (technically, unity-2d). You can find this options by clicking on the Ubuntu logo beside your name in the login screen. (in case you don't get a login screen when you turn the PC on, try to "log out" from the desktop, change that option, and login again.)
3. Try to not keep different applications open at the same time. Finish your work with one, close it down, and get to another one. (of course you will need a few applications always open, like a browser)

That's all comes to my mind right now.

Answer (score 0):

I run 12.04 on a laptop with only 1GB ram and it runs okay. I had to use Unity2d because Unity3d was really sluggish. Using another window manager other than Unity would probably make it snappier.