# What are the minimum System Requirements for 12.04 LTS on a 2GB environment

Tags: 12.04, lts, toshiba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the minimum system requirements for 12.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125280/what-are-the-minimum-system-requirements-for-12-04-lts)

I have 2GB RAM and an INTEL CORE DUO(3.73Ghz), it's a Toshiba Satellite L310. It doesn't work well in Ubuntu 11.04. If I install the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, will it be lag again?

Comment: Please see this similar question [What are the minimum system requirements for 12.04 LTS?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/125280/what-are-the-minimum-system-requirements-for-12-04-lts)

Comment: I have roughly same specs, but it run as smooth as mbp. Try 12.04

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't expect the lag to get better by upgrading to 12.04, although some recent changes in the kernel did improve the performance. I also would not expect it to get worse, though.
I have recently installed 12.04 on a few computers going further back than the core era of processors and generally only had 1G ram. I haven't had problems and it wasn't particularly slow (definitely way faster than an XP install on the same hardware).