# How much memory does Ubuntu need?

Tags: memory, system-requirements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the minimum system requirements for 12.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125280/what-are-the-minimum-system-requirements-for-12-04-lts)

How much memory do I need for Ubuntu? I mean everything that is taking memory space after I finished installing it.

Comment: Base install is in between 2 and 2.2 Gb but you need a bit more if you want to use it. As shoun by @amol sale 5 Gb is the minumum (and I think Ubuntu will also abort the installation if it thinks there is not enough space)

Answer (score 6):

According to [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements/), System Requirements are

**Ubuntu Desktop Edition**

- 512 MiB RAM (system memory)
- 5 GB of hard-drive space

**Ubuntu Server (CLI) Installation**

- 128 MiB of system memory (RAM)
- 1 GB of disk space

**Lightweight GUI alternative (Xubuntu and Lubuntu)**

- 512 MiB of system memory (RAM)
- 5 GB of disk space

**Ubuntu Netbook Edition**

- 386 MiB of system memory (RAM)
- 4 GB of disk space

Comment: Thank you for your fast and useful answers.....it's really easy to solve problems here