# Can I install Ubuntu on my system?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7

The capacity of my hard drive 500GB and I have 1GB of RAM . Can I install Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7 on my system as dual Boot?

Comment: YES: http://askubuntu.com/a/125282/14564

Comment: Will my pc get slow?

Comment: I would reccomend using Lubuntu as it is tailored to work on machines with less performance. As for Wondows 7 it will work too but it will work a bit slow due to little mem. Of course you can turn off all the useless features what will speed up it a little.

Comment: You forgot to mention what CPU do you have

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the minimum system requirements for 12.04 LTS?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/125280/what-are-the-minimum-system-requirements-for-12-04-lts)

Answer (score 4):

You should understand that there's no difference if you're dual-booting with Windows 7 or not (well, maybe only in terms of disk space available) - the performance of the system will be the same as if Windows or Ubuntu were the only OS on the machine.

If you're happy with how Windows runs on the machine now, then it'll be no different after you install Ubuntu.

1 Gb of RAM is not a lot by modern standards, but it's more than Ubuntu's minimal requirements, so Ubuntu will run OK too.