# System requirements for Ubuntu 12.04.1 32bit?

Tags: 12.04, system-requirements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the minimum system requirements for 12.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125280/what-are-the-minimum-system-requirements-for-12-04-lts)

My PC is running windows 7 [32bit] and I was wondering if my system will support the latest Ubuntu.
**My System Specifications:**
**Processor:** Intel Core2 Duo CPU  E4600 @ 2.4Ghz 2.4Ghz
**RAM:** 1 GB

Answer (score 0):

Should be very speedy on your machine compared to Windows 7 ;) 1 GB should be enough to run it.