# System requirements for ubuntu 12.04(Will it run on 512MB RAM?)

Tags: system-requirements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the minimum system requirements for 12.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125280/what-are-the-minimum-system-requirements-for-12-04-lts)
>   [How do I find out which version and derivate of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minmal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivate-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardware)

I have a Fujitsu Siemens Amilo D 1840 laptop and I was wondering will ubuntu 12.04 run normally, once installed with wubi. I have an Intel Pentium 4 3.02 Ghz processor and 512 MB RAM, as mentioned in the title.

P.S. Excuse me if my english is bad, but I'm from Bulgaria

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the "Minimum Hardware Requirements" mentioned in the  "[**Installation Guide**](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/powerpc/minimum-hardware-reqts.html)" for PowerPC, the answer is YES.

Nevertheless in the real world, a one core microprocessor with less than 1GB RAM will result in a less efficient computer "feeling" slow in many aspects.

You must consider seriously what is mentioned in the given page, specially what refers to the graphic desktop environments, as follows:

> The actual minimum memory requirements are a lot less then the numbers
>   listed in this table. Depending on the architecture, it is possible to
>   install Ubuntu with as little as 20MB (for s390) to 48MB (for i386 and
>   amd64). The same goes for the disk space requirements, especially if
>   you pick and choose which applications to install; see the section
>   called “Disk Space Needed” for additional information on disk space
>   requirements.
>
> It is possible to run a graphical desktop environment on older or
>   low-end systems, but in that case it is recommended to install a
>   window manager that is less resource-hungry than those of the GNOME or
>   KDE desktop environments; alternatives include xfce4, icewm and
>   wmaker, but there are others to choose from.

Anyway, there are lightweight desktop environments and several distributions based on ubuntu (lxde and lubuntu comes to my mind), which makes a difference in "speed" at the very moment that you use the computer to do something, apart from the boot itself.

You must remember that the "speed" of a computer is a sensation. Something you "feel" based on several things, not only the speed of the microprocessor and RAM.

## **Recapitulating:**

***The fast answer is YES, it will run. But you may expect a slow performance computer after all.***

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Just my 2cents:

If I were in your shoes I would opt for the XUbuntu official variant. It is a fully fledged Ubuntu Linux environment, without the resource hog named Unity 3d, featuring the XFCE graphical user interface in Unity's place, which is known to be notoriously lightweight.

Some screenshots:

App selection:
[image]

File Manager:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No - not really, performance will be poor.
With only 512mb RAM you would be much better off using a lighter distro such as Lubuntu or Xubuntu, see links below.

[Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/)

[Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/)

Comment: +1 the Lubuntu/Xubuntu will be better but if OP really wants standard Ubuntu the 32bit version's minimal requirements are [384MB](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop#System_requirements) so the 32bit may also be acceptable....but still slower than the above listed alternatives I would suspect

Answer (score 1):

You can find the minimum system requirements for Ubuntu on [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements/).

Your laptop should run Ubuntu just fine, though since 512MB is on the low end, it's possible that you may have a better experience using Unity2D as opposed to Unity3D. I doubt it will be necessary, particularly given your processor speed, but if you find that even Unity2D is slower than you would like, you could also try using a more lightweight Desktop Environment such as LXDE or XFCE.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a machine with 512 MB RAM and it run pretty well.
Although the performance was pretty decent while using it with default set of preinstalled software (I didn't launch any server applications or stuff like that) I had around 20 MB of free RAM after boot.

So, unless you need it to be really snappy and fast (or use it for some extra apps like: SQL , WWW server ) you should be alright - without a "WOW that's fast" :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to download the [alternate, text-based installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads) of Ubuntu. This will avoid problems during the installation due to little memory.

Also, you may want to have a look at Lubuntu, a very light version of Ubuntu. I personally didn't have a good experience with that distribution, but you can try it. [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Alternate_ISO) is the alternate, text-based installer of Lubuntu (again, use it to avoid memory problems during the installation).