# Running Ubuntu on HP Compaq Presario CQ58 AMD E-300 1.3GHz 4GB Ram 320GB HD

Tags: installation, dual-boot

Is anyone out there running Ubuntu on HP Compaq Presario CQ58 Notebook PC?

If so what version and are there any issues I need to know about?

Can I dual boot with Windows 8 currently running?

Laptop Specs: Compaq Presario CQ58 Notebook PC AMD E-300 1.3 GHz 4GB Ram 320gb HD

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [System requirements for ubuntu 12.04(Will it run on 512MB RAM?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/182310/system-requirements-for-ubuntu-12-04will-it-run-on-512mb-ram)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there are any bugs on this particular model, but I would try the newest version (driver support/security updates) of Ubuntu.

For Dual-Booting Ubuntu with Windows 8 on your Notebook, which has UEFI, [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) will help you.

[Here](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-Systems-and-Software/disable-uefi-boot-in-compaq-presario-CQ58-351SM/td-p/3020703) is a guide for disabling secure boot and going to legacy mode if you need to do that, but I doubt it.

This is from the guide i linked:

> To install Ubuntu in EFI mode:
>
> 1. Use a 64bit disk of Ubuntu (Ubuntu32bit cannot be easily installed in
>      UEFI mode)
> 2. Use a supported version of Ubuntu. Support for UEFI appeared in 11.10,
>      but has become more reliable in next versions. Support for UEFI
>      SecureBoot appeared in 12.10 and 12.04.2.
> 3. Set up your firmware (BIOS) to boot the disk in UEFI mode (see the
>      "Identifying if the computer boots the HDD in EFI mode" paragraph
>      below)
> 4. Then: nothing special is required if you use the automatic installer
>      of Ubuntu ("Install Ubuntu alongside others" or "Erase the disk and
>      install Ubuntu"). Important: if you have a pre-installed Windows and
>      you want to keep it, do not choose "Erase the disk and install
>      Ubuntu". if you use the manual partitioning ("Something else"), the
>      difference is that you will have to set the /boot/efi mount point to
>      the EFI partition. And if there was not any EFI partition on your HDD,
>      you first will have to create it (see the "Creating an EFI partition"
>      paragraph below).

Actually you need to be careful with the partitioning if you make them manually because most new laptops contain a "recovery-partition" which replaces the installation CDs of Windows.