# What are the minimum system requirements for ubuntu 12.04 desktop?

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the minimum system requirements for 12.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125280/what-are-the-minimum-system-requirements-for-12-04-lts)

Sir,
    I am a LINUX beginner. I want to use ubuntu 12.04 desktop version on my system. So I want to know the minimum system and internet requirements. I have WINDOWS XP SP2, 1GB of RAM, 160GB HD and a 256kbps bandwidth dial up connection. Are these enough to use ubuntu 12.04 desktop?? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

According to Ubuntu the requirements for Ubuntu Desktop are,

```
1. 700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
2. 512 MiB RAM (system memory)
3. 5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
4. VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
5. Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
6. Internet access is helpful
```

For requirements for other types are give [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements/).