# New to Ubuntu: Have "old" MSI netbook with XP. Will Ubuntu work?

Tags: ubuntu-netbook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the minimum system requirements for 12.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125280/what-are-the-minimum-system-requirements-for-12-04-lts)

I am taking the netbook on the road but I'd like upgrade the OS and Windows 7 is out of the question. Netbook has only 2GB RAM. Will Ubuntu work and can I get rid of XP in the process? Thx!

Comment: Check this out: http://askubuntu.com/questions/125280/what-are-the-minimum-system-requirements-for-12-04-lts ; Lubuntu might be a good option for you (its a lightweight ubuntu-based linux distribution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to find out is to try! You can load a livecd to test it out without messing your system up. Also, Ubuntu 12.10 has removed Unity 2D but I think they have done some work to make it auto fail back to something your machine will handle if your hardware can't handle Unity 3D.

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/08/unity-2d-removed-from-ubuntu-12-10

Comment: Thanks, Elijah! Why is it called a "live" cd? A cd may be the way to go for me bc I have a limited data plan. I'd like to think I'm reasonably tech savy but Ubuntu may as well be from Uranus to me. Where do I send away for the cd?

Comment: Oops, wait a minute! My netbook doesn't have a cd drive. Duh. I've used thumb drives in the past...

Comment: It is traditionally called a LiveCD because you just put it in and it loads the whole OS into memory, never touching your disk. When you turn the computer off (disc removed) it is exactly the way it was before you put the cd in. ---- Now, it is much more common to make a Live USB, also saves a poor disc from the landfill.

Comment: OK, when you say "never touching the disk", you mean hard drive, right?

Comment: Yes, "never touching the disk" can mean hard drive, hdd or even ssd.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. If XP works reasonably, you are going to have **awesome** experience with Ubuntu. 2GB is totally enough! Most likely your laptop is going to gain another life if you install Ubuntu 12.04 on it. **So go ahead and give it a try!**

Comment: Thx raf. Or Rafa. Elijah above suggested a "live" cd. Might be a good idea as I don't know how big of a chunk of data the download is. Do you concur?

Comment: Disregard that:  I just remembered i don't have a cd drive! What about a thumb drive or even an sd card?