# System Requirements for Ubuntu 12.0x?

Tags: system-requirements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the minimum system requirements for 12.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125280/what-are-the-minimum-system-requirements-for-12-04-lts)

I just want to know what are the minimum system requirements for Ubuntu 12.x in general!

Please help me a be specific, because other answer only pertain to other people's computer systems.

Answer (score 0):

700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
512 MiB RAM (system memory)
5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution

Reference: [Ubuntu System Requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)