# Ressource difference between server and desktop

Tags: 12.04, server, 12.10

How much difference, ressourcewise, is there between the two versions?

Also what's version would you reccomend? 12.04 or 12.10?

Comment: What do you mean by "ressourcewise"? What resources are you referring to?

Comment: CPU and RAM. Also how much of a GPU is needed if I'll actually want to show a desktop for the ease of a home server.

Comment: Both are impossible to answer. It depends on hardware and on usage for instance. Choice of 12.04 and 12.10 depends on what your usage is too: if the system is a production server LTS is the best way to go (=12.04)

Comment: See [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/125280/what-are-the-minimum-system-requirements-for-12-04-lts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask two different questions, I'll address the 12.04 vs 12.10 here. In a very subjective way, because it is a subjective issue.

12.04 is the LTS (long term support) version. I have excellent experience with LTS Ubuntu; my main workstation runs 10.04 LTS and I still do not see a reason to upgrade. Personally, I opt for 12.04. I'm old, and the time flows very quickly; I remember installing 10.04 as if it was yesterday. I don't want to fiddle with installations too often.

12.10 will soon be replaced by another Ubuntu version, and will not be supported in the long run. However, it features [all what is new and shiny](http://www.iloveubuntu.net/ubuntu-1210-released), including web apps and commercials from Amazon.